# Shoulda-matchers are not seen by rails/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 4.2.4, Rspec 3.3.1, shoulda-matchers 3.0.0.

I am getting

```
  #...
  358) Participant validations 
       Failure/Error: it { should ensure_length_of(:coresp_country).is_at_most(255) }
       NoMethodError:
         undefined method `ensure_length_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Participant::Validations:0x0000000f40aec0>
       # ./spec/models/participant_spec.rb:100:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  359) Participant validations company 
       Failure/Error: it { should ensure_length_of(:company).is_at_most(255) }
       NoMethodError:
         undefined method `ensure_length_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Participant::Validations::Company:0x0000000f414ab0>
       # ./spec/models/participant_spec.rb:149:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  360) Participant validations company declared_type = COMPANY 
       Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:company) }
       NoMethodError:
         undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Participant::Validations::Company::DeclaredTypeCOMPANY:0x0000000f429c58>
   #...
```

And many more failures of this kind (looks like shoulda-matchers do not work).

rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

Rails.logger.level = 4

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
  config.include Macros::Controller::Security
end
FactoryGirl.reload
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'simplecov_helper'
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
require 'rspec/collection_matchers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.disable_monkey_patching!
  config.expose_dsl_globally = true
  config.default_formatter = 'doc' if config.files_to_run.one?
  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

---

## EDIT

Ok, I think the issue is not with shoulda-matchers, but with [active_attr gem](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr), because tests only fails in `spec/compositions/api` folder, where I use the gem.

Comment: Sorry for kinda poking at the most obvious case, but is rails_helper.rb required in given specs? Maybe you have accidentially required spec_helper.rb

Comment: `rails_helper.rb` is required :)

Comment: Alright, next checkpoint: no require: false in gem 'shoulda-matchers' ? ;-)

Comment: when `require: false` I get `uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)
` pointing to `Shoulda::Matchers.configure` line in `rails_helper.rb`

Comment: That makes sense, just wanted to make sure the require: false is NOT in there, some tutorials suggest you do so and then require it manually. I'm not entirely sure how the require mechanic for bundled gems work there, but I think it's important that you have the 'shoulda-matchers' gem in the test-group within your Gemfile, is that checked too?

Comment: yeap, in `test` group

Comment: That's a tough one. Our settings are almost identical, try commenting out disable_monkey_patching maybe, I could imagine that the thoughtbot folks monkeypatched something and that breaks it.

Comment: tried this one (should have changed `describe` to `RSpec.describe`) - no luck unfortunately..

Comment: Alright, thats my last shot, almost out of ideas. You can require: false the gem in the Gemfile and require 'shoulda/matchers' in your rails_helper.rb file (after rspec/rails). Also there's no application preloader like spring/spork involved, right?

Comment: I've tried this before, but will try one more time, and yeah, no spring/spork involved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) 3.0 selectively makes its matchers available. I am using ActiveModel matchers which are only mixed into model specs ([af98a23](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/af98a23091551fb40aded5a8d4f9e5be926f53a9)).

I had two options to solve the issue:

- placing the specs of the models, which use [active_attr](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr) gem under `spec/models` folder;
- adding `type: :model` to the top-level describe block for each class in `spec/compositions/api` folder.

I decided to go with second option and it worked.

---

**Sidenote**

Now matchers, which starts with ensure (`ensure_inclusion_in`, `ensure_length_of`) are renamed to `validate_inclusion_in`, `validate_length_of` ([55c8d09](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/55c8d09bf2af886540924efa83c3b518d926a770)).

Comment: Thanks for this (particularly the side note). Saved my sanity

Comment: @JayDorsey I remember I was about to loose mine when finally worked it out :D Glad it is helpful for someone other than me!